# Google sign-in with Java Spring security application

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google sign-in into an existing Spring security application. The goal is to have a Google sign-in button that will allow a user to log in along with the standard login using the username/password combination.

Based on the guide that Google provides (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) it looks like **all I need to do is extend the login form** (that currently only has the login and the password input fields) **with an extra field "id_token"** and submit it to the server.

**Would it be a good security practice?** I searched the web and I am surprised I cannot find any similar implementations on the web.

Comment: You will need to take care of several issues. How would you manage local users for Spring Sec Application and external users from Google? How will be principals from Google  translated to Spring Sec principal? Those are the two which I can tell from top of my mind.

Comment: " How would you manage local users for Spring Sec Application and external users from Google?"  I will manage them the same creating a new user if the doesn't exist already. 
"How will be principals from Google translated to Spring Sec principal?"
I will have to provide an option to the Google user to bind the Spring sec user by specifying a valid login/password combination (that the spring user was registered with).

Answer (score 4):

Here is my take on the required spring-security components:

filter:

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GoogleIdAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String tokenParamName = "googleIdToken";

    /**
     * Creates an instance which will authenticate against the supplied
     * {@code AuthenticationManager} and which will ignore failed authentication attempts,
     * allowing the request to proceed down the filter chain.
     *
     * @param authenticationManager     the bean to submit authentication requests to
     * @param defaultFilterProcessesUrl the url to check for auth requests on (e.g. /login/google)
     */
    public GoogleIdAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        Assert.notNull(authenticationManager, "authenticationManager cannot be null");
        setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String token = request.getParameter(tokenParamName);

        if (token == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug("Google ID Token Authorization parameter found with value '" + token + "'");
        }

        Object details = this.authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request);

        GoogleIdAuthenticationToken authRequest = new GoogleIdAuthenticationToken(token, details);

        Authentication authResult = getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);

        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug("Authentication success: " + authResult);
        }

        return authResult;
    }

    public String getTokenParamName() {
        return tokenParamName;
    }

    public void setTokenParamName(String tokenParamName) {
        this.tokenParamName = tokenParamName;
    }
}
```

authentication provider:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.Payload;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityMessageSource;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;

public class GoogleIdAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoogleIdAuthenticationProvider.class);

    private String clientId;

    @Resource
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private HttpTransport httpTransport = new ApacheHttpTransport();
    private JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    protected MessageSourceAccessor messages = SpringSecurityMessageSource.getAccessor();

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (!supports(authentication.getClass())) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug(String.format("This authentication provider does not support instances of type %s", authentication.getClass().getName()));
            }
            return null;
        }

        GoogleIdAuthenticationToken googleIdAuthenticationToken = (GoogleIdAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
            logger.debug(String.format("Validating google login with token '%s'", googleIdAuthenticationToken.getCredentials()));


        GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory)
                .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(getClientId()))
                .build();

        GoogleIdToken googleIdToken = null;
        try {
            googleIdToken = verifier.verify((String) googleIdAuthenticationToken.getCredentials());

            if (googleIdToken == null) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Unable to verify token");
            }
        } catch (IOException|GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Unable to verify token", e);
        }

        Payload payload = googleIdToken.getPayload();

        // Get profile information from payload
        String email = payload.getEmail();

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(String.format("Loading user details for email '%s'", email));
        }
        UserDetails userDetails = null;
        try {
            userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(email);

            if (!userDetails.isAccountNonLocked()) {
                throw new LockedException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.locked", "User account is locked"));
            }

            if (!userDetails.isEnabled()) {
                throw new DisabledException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.disabled", "User is disabled"));
            }

            if (!userDetails.isAccountNonExpired()) {
                throw new AccountExpiredException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.expired", "User account has expired"));
            }
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
            // provision a new user?
            throw e;
        }

        return new GoogleIdAuthenticationToken((String) googleIdAuthenticationToken.getCredentials(), userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getAuthorities(), authentication.getDetails());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return (GoogleIdAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }

    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }
}
```

token:

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class GoogleIdAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {
    private String credentials;
    private Object principal;

    public GoogleIdAuthenticationToken(String token, Object details) {
        super(new ArrayList<>());
        this.credentials = token;
        setDetails(details);
        setAuthenticated(false);
    }

    GoogleIdAuthenticationToken(String token, String principal, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, Object details) {
        super(authorities);
        this.credentials = token;
        this.principal = principal;
        setDetails(details);
        setAuthenticated(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return credentials;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return principal;
    }
}
```

After plugging in the above you'll just need to POST to "/login/google" (or whatever you've configured) with the token returned by Google in the 'googleIdToken' (or whatever you've configured).

Comment: The property "clientId" of the AuthenticationProvider which value would have? I followed that steps but I don't know how to initialize that value.

Comment: Sorry, I've just realized that clientId is the id given by Google's API console to the auth project. I'll vote up your response.

Comment: This answer is really useful and helped me a lot, thanks! I should note that the "plumbing" part was not straight-forward and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44144412/5352605) helped me. Basically I did `http.addFilterBefore(new GoogleIdAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, "/login/google"), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);` but ymmv.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am sharing some code which I have used for server-side Google sign token verification using spring. It is a working example :

```
@Autowired
HttpTransport transport;
 
private static final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

public void verify(String idTokenString)
{
    GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory).setAudience(Collections.singletonList(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID))
                .build();
        GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
        IdToken.Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
        Boolean emailVerified = (Boolean) payload.get("email_verified");
        if (if (idToken != null) {
        String email = (String) payload.get("email");
        String fname = (String) payload.get("given_name");
        String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
        String lname = (String) payload.get("family_name");
}
```

Dependencies:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.40.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

So, the right answer turned out to be not extending the existing auth filter/provider but defining/adding another {Token Authentication class + token auth filter + token auth provider (provider is kind of optional)}