# Spring Boot Oauth2 use multiple grant_types for for same URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-oauth2

Is it possible to configure Spring Boot to allow `Oauth2` grant types `password` and `authorization_code` on the same URL. For example `/boot`

I have done basic authorization configuration as below

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://UAA/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://UAA/oauth/authorize
      clientId: ******
      clientSecret: ******
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://UAA/userinfo
```

However all endpoints protected by this configuration use form login and redirect to `UAA` authorization URL even when request is sent with `Authorization Bearer ****` token header. That means even when I send a `Authorization` token in postman I get `HTTP Status 302` along with `HTML` response for UAA login page.

Comment: So, what was your fix for this? Could really do with an answer

Comment: Apologies for late comment. I never solved it, instead I settled for having two different URLs protected by two different security configurations. Meaning I mapped each end-point in my app to two different URLs i.e. (/auth/home, /pass/home). Since all I had was REST endpoints it was just a matter of adding one additional path entry in @RequestMapping. Check this answer for the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/44440735/5343269 .

Comment: If you really want to achieve this with single URL you can try intercepting coming request in a Filter and if request contains `Authorization` header you can manually initiate Spring Security's Oauth2 token processing or you can manually validate token and populate `SecurityContextHolder`. It will take some work, but its not impossible. Check this answer for details of how to populate SecurityContextHolder manully https://stackoverflow.com/a/44144412/5343269

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having configs in config file, you can configure authorization server to create OAuth clients. Then you can configure clients with multiple grant types, authorities, scopes etc...

```
   @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory().withClient("client_id").authorizedGrantTypes("password", "client_credentials")
                    .secret("secret").authorities("Authority1", "Authority2").scopes("READ", "WRITE").resourceIds("resource_server_id");
    }
```

Please check [This Spring OAuth sample](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was asking from the client's perspective. There's already an authorization server managed by third party, I want my application to allow multiple granty_types on the same URL.