# Multiple grant types for one client application with Spring Boot Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm programming a client (Spring Boot application) which has to provide two endpoints for a user, one which uses Authorization Code Grant, and the other which uses Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant. Endpoints are on different URLs. The other one will be used by internal application so I'm not concerned about security.

I have an external OAuth2 server (both authorization and resource server) - so I'm not programming those but I have full access to their configuration. Keycloak is in question.

I've managed to set up Authorization Code Grant, but cannot get the other one to work.

My application.yml looks something like:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      token-info-uri: ...3rd party...
      userInfoUri: ...3rd party...
    client:
          client-id: ...
          client-secret: ...
          grant-type: authorization_code
          registered-redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/app/auth_grant
          pre-established-redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/app/auth_grant/
          user-authorization-uri: ...3rd party uri...
          access-token-uri:  ...3rd party uri...
          scope:
            - read
            - write
            - openid
```

I have an WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation annotated with  `@EnableOAuth2Sso` 
 `@Configuration` which permits only */login* to be accessed unauthorized.

Now I want my users to be able to login with Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant at (example) */login_ROPCG*.

I've read the documentation but I guess I've headed in the wrong direction. Can you give me some hints?

I've read this comment: [Spring Boot Oauth2 use multiple grant_types for for same URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404610/spring-boot-oauth2-use-multiple-grant-types-for-for-same-url#comment101722906_50404610)
In which the hint is that I need two different security configurations with different mapping but I don't know how to do this.

I've read this: [How can I implement Basic Authentication with JWT authentication in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302457/how-can-i-implement-basic-authentication-with-jwt-authentication-in-spring-boot/44440735#44440735) but I don't see how to set two different grant types.

And because of this I'm not sure is this even possible: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14554

Comment: @dur yes, I use Spring Security 5.2.0. I want to do that because we have some old app which uses old API which sends username and password for authentication. Which corresponds to the usecase in the RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3) _This grant type is suitable for clients capable of obtaining the resource owner's credentials (username and password, typically using an interactive form). It is also used to migrate existing clients using direct authentication schemes such as HTTP Basic or Digest authentication to OAuth by converting the stored credentials to an access token._

Comment: Still no progress. I have a problem with password grant in spring boot. I can't override WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter because the default resolver set by .oauth2Login in configuration method doesn't know how to resolve Password grant.